# (As or Provided) you get your father's permission, I'll take you skiing next weekend

Tags: word-choice

I am taking an online [English skill test](http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/adult-learners) and noticed there's a question like this:

> ___ you get your father's permission, I'll take you skiing next weekend.
>
> (As) OR (Provided)

The correct answer is `Provided` according to the page. I am wondering why `As` is not ok for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not valid because as a conjunction, `as` can mean several things: [Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/As)

> 1. To the same degree or quantity that. Often used as a correlative after so or as: You are as sweet as sugar. The situation is not so bad
>    as you suggest.
> 2. In the same manner or way that: Think as I think.
>
> **3. At the same time that; while: slipped on the ice as I ran home.**
>
> 4. For the reason that; because: went to bed early, as I was exhausted.
> 5. With the result that: He was so foolish as to lie.
> 6. Though: Great as the author was, he proved a bad model. Ridiculous as it seems, the tale is true.
> 7. In accordance with which or with the way in which: The hotel is quite comfortable as such establishments go. The sun is hot, as
>    everyone knows.
> 8. Informal That: I don't know as I can answer your question.

I think clause 3, which I highlighted above, is what has you confused. The speaker is telling the kid that she/he will take him skiing *after* he gets his father's permission, not *while* he is getting it.

Answer (score 1):

You use the conjunction "provided" in subordinate clause to make it conditional, meaning "if or only if" while you cannot use "as" in this sense. So the use of "as" is not appropriate in this sentence.  However, the sentence  "As you have got your father's permission, I'll take you skiing next weekend is OK. Here, the use of "as" means "because/since".